# Restrict access from internet in apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have a web app that is accessible via Internet, my folder structure is like this.

```
Folder1

 Folder2

 Files.php

abc.php
```

I want to give access to Folder1 to a specific IP only and give access to abc.php to Everyone on Internet, Here is what I have done but its not working

```
<Directory /var/www/Folder1>

Allow from 19.1.5.2

<Files /var/www/Folder1/abc.php>

Allow from All

</Files>

</Directory>
```

But it is not working , am I missing something ?

Comment: Not sure how or if it's possible to configure apache to do this through .htaccess/vhost config, but I do know that it's typical for developers to move any non-web-accessable content to a folder outside of the web root.  Then, after authentication/checking IP, use a web-accessable PHP file to call the appropriate files from the non-web-accessable folder. But alas, I don't know what you're attempting to do really with these folders, so this may not work for you.

Comment: you need a `Deny from all` you're still allowing all to access

Comment: @MikelBitson yes that is another option to put restricted files in some seperate folder.

Comment: @Dagon after Allow from specific IP ?

Comment: before, first block every one, the specify who to let in

Comment: @Dagon that means it will just deny from all IPs and wont go in <Files> directive.

Comment: it should deny all then allow in the specific cases, are you saying that does not happen?

Comment: @Dagon yes it doesn't work, just the first part works , the directory is blocked for that ip, but file is not accessible as well.

Comment: @UsmanSm did you even try my answer?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes I have created htaccess file and tried that with my IP but it fails

Answer (score 1):

Try using rewrite for this. See if this will work for you. Put this in your .htaccess file in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.\123\.123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Folder1/abc.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.\123\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Folder1/abc.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: How did this work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can allow the file within the protected folder. Here is how to protect the folder, though.

Put this .htaccess in the root of Folder1

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all

<Limit GET HEAD POST>
  Allow from 19.1.5.2
</Limit>
```